# sqlite3 read bound values for a prepared statement

Tags: c, sqlite

Is it possible to read back bound values for a sqlite3 prepared statement. I don't see any api in [here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) to do this.

Also is it possible to check if bindings are cleared for a prepared statement.

Comment: I think it's assumed that you already know them, given you set them.

Comment: Thanks true, but I have a  use-case where in if statement is already executed for a WHERE clause, and if results are present I need not execute (step) the statement again.

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep state, which is something that almost always needs doing.